# I have the following two questions for application derivative, in particular chain rule, but I am not sure if my interpretation is right.

Tags: calculus

1.A particle moves in the plane according to the law $y = x^3−3x+5$ so that $x =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t}+3,$
where $t$ is time. At what rate is $y$ changing when $t = 4$?

My answer:  $\left.\frac{dy}{dt}\right|_{t=4}=\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}\right|_{t=4}=\frac{45}{8}$

2.A particle moves in the plane according to the law $x = t^2 + 2t$, $y = 2t^3 − 6t$. Find the slope of the tangent line when $t = 0$.

My answer: $\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{t=0}=\left.\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}\right|_{t=0}=-3$

Now I ask myself, the rate at which $y$ changes at $t_0$ and the slope of the tangent line when $t=t_0$ sound like the same thing to me, I wonder why to answer the first question I calculated $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and did not think to do that in the second question, that is if my answers are even correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct.  The second is not because $\frac {dt}{dx}=\dfrac 1{\frac {dx}{dt}}$.  You were trying to calculate the correct thing in the second.  The slope of the tangent is different from $\frac {dy}{dt}$.  The slope of the tangent does not depend on how quickly the curve is traversed, while $\frac {dy}{dt}$ is proportional to the rate at which the curve is traversed.